# How to get Attachments list for an article view in format=raw output

Tags: format

Using this Joomla Attachment plugin: http://jmcameron.net/attachments/

When used `&format=raw` in the url params to view an article the output only shows the details of the article and its categories and nothing about the Attachments that we have attached to that article.

How can we get the list of attachments too in the raw format display? Name of the attached file or full url.